# how to disabled date in zebra datepicker which date coming through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Please help me for find result:

```
var hopid=$("#hospital").val();
        var docid=$("#doctor").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>doctor/referral/getdoctordate",
            data: {'hosid' : hopid,'docid':docid},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg)
            {
               alert(msg.date);
            }

public function getdoctordate()
{

$row['result'] = $this->my_model->getdocdate();
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code and be clear with what you actually want to do

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" style="cursor:pointer;" placeholder="Date of Refer" id="datepicker123" >

Comment: i want to disabled some date in zebra datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed configuration information you can get from [project's homepage](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/)
Coming towards problem how to disable group of different dates in date picker, it is done as

```
$("#datepicker123").Zebra_DatePicker({
      direction: true,
      disabled_dates: [
        '05 02 2017',
        '09 02 2017',
        '15 02 2017',
      ]
    });
```

this will disable 5th,9th and 15th date of feb 2017 disabled

So your code would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#some_button').click(function(){
    var hopid=$("#hospital").val();
    var docid=$("#doctor").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>doctor/referral/getdoctordate",
    data: {'hosid' : hopid,'docid':docid},
    dataType: "json",
   success: function(msg)

    //var msg=JSON.parse(msg)
    var dates=[];
     for(i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
        var date_formate = msg[i].date.replace(/-/g, ' ');
        dates.push(date_formate)
      }

    $("#datepicker123").Zebra_DatePicker({
      direction: true,
      disabled_dates: dates
    });
   })

 })
})
```

Here msg.date is the array of disabled date

Comment: thank you for helping me but its showing this error in console SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: yes i am tried but when i use alert(msg) its showing like this:[object object],[object object]

Comment: please hep me its important for me

Comment: alert(dates), what is result

Comment: top left where answer start just below  arrow down mark is there is tick mark just click it